# DevicePolicyManager, locknow when gcm message received

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to remotely lock my phone when a gcm PUSH notification with a keyword arrives.

Inside the GcmIntentService class, within the onHandleIntent I have included

```
 message = extras.getString("message");
                if(message.equals("LOCK")){
                    gcmaction(message);
                }
                else{
                     sendNotification("Message: " + extras.getString("message"));
                     Log.i(TAG, "Message: " + extras.toString());
                }
```

So if a message arrives saying LOCK, it should go to the gcmaction method. Otherwise go to the notification method.

private void gcmaction(String string) {

```
  mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

    //lock action
        mDPM.resetPassword(Password,
                   DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
        mDPM.lockNow();
```

}

sendNotification is correctly showing notfications but nothing happens when I send "LOCK" ... can someone tell me what I am missing ?

Thanks

Comment: When you used a debugger, or `Log` statements, to examine `message`, are you actually ever getting `LOCK`? Is your app set up in Settings to be a device administrator?

Comment: Before invoking lockNow method, you should check if your app is activated as Device Admin or not using isAdminActive(ComponentName cn) method in DevicePolicyManager class.